# dropping verb 'to be' like in 'How you acting funny in a drama movie?'

Tags: grammar

'You say you a god, who you running to?', 'Who you?', 'How you doing?'

What's up with that thing? Why do natives sometimes drop am/are/is?

Comment: do you have the source for any of these? The 3rd I have heard (in movies and real life), but the 1st to sound (to me) like bad cliches.  In general, there are many regional terms of speech in Canada, the U.S., and England, so given the great variety of possibilities, it's not surprising that there is a wide variety of possibilities.  In addition, some are affected (e.g., for movies)

Comment: Because English is weird, and people change bits of it to mark themselves out as part of a group. Nothing arcane to it, unfortunately.

Comment: @michael sure, these are from the song Static by Lucki

Comment: Don't know anything about this singer but just listened to it.  With singers, especially rap-type singers, really ANYTHING goes in terms of rearranging / massaging (some would say butchering) the language.  The same is true to (generally to a lesser extent) in slam poetry and to a much lesser extent in traditional poetry.  It's about being edgy/unique, branding your style, and (more generously) establishing/keeping a beat or rhyming scheme)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes it's hard to distinguish between unique features of a singer and unknown to me features of a language

Comment: I would put it differently from @michael: while there is always (in all ages) a tendency for poets to push their language beyond its normal limits, I strongly suspect that Rap and other genres do have a normally consistent grammar, but that it is different from standard English grammar. I have no doubt there are elements from [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) in it: the grammar of _be_ in AAVE is famously very different from standard English

Comment: @ColinFine - point taken and valid. However, rap is not (anymore) restricted to African Americans or even AAVE.  Rap is now global (including in English by non-English artists).  At any rate, I hope I didn't come across denigrating rap (or AAVE rap) as a whole (even though I have opinions on certain artists).

Comment: While I'm here,  I should also add that words/language can be used/stretched/misused/abused (and not just by rap to be sure) to convey a sense of emotion / urgency (in addition to the reasons I listed earlier - and I'm sure there are more)

Comment: @michael and I think we can all agree that the worst rappers are the white ones who talk and act like they're African-Americans... *cough* Vanilla Ice *end cough*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lyrics are written by [Lucki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucki) - an African-American rapper - using an English variety referred to as [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) or AAVE for short. One of the [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English#Other_grammatical_characteristics) of AAVE is that the verb "to be" in its various forms is often dropped. In your example, it's dropped 4 times.

There are other English varieties which share features with AAVE, e.g. [Southern American English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English). Off the top of my head, I don't have other good examples of a variety where "to be" is dropped as prominently - others might know more.